# why not show androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I create a BaseActivity to create a toolbar and setSupportActionBar() in onCreate(). But its subclass can not show toolbar. Why?

part of styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

part of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name=".utils.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

layout file common_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/comm_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

parent class BaseActivity

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.comm_toolbar)
        val toolBar =
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.comm_toolbar,
                null,false) as androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar)
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your MainActivity's setContentView sets the activity_main layout as the content view. There is no toolbar in that layout. The BaseActivity's contentView is no longer set so setSupportActionBar(toolBar) no longer works.

You can do handle this by adding a toolbar in your child activities or using a viewstub in the base activity's xml below the toolbar in a constraintlayout and inflating the child activity's layout in the viewstub of the parent. This would keep the toolbar and load the child activity's view as well